# How do you make thumbnails of videos? Using flowplayer free

Tags: php, flash

I'm making a "video sharing site" just for learning and fun. I am using `FlowPlayer` as my player for videos. Now Im gonna make a page that will list every video, and a want preview picture of the video. Like: http://www.youtube.com/videos

How do you do that? With the player or can you do it with php?? Ive looked true Flowplayer forums. But I cant find anything.

Would really appricate some help.

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg is the usual utility to handle video, both to convert and making thumbnails

from PHP it being handled using `system()` function, as any other command-line utility

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps do you know a good guide on this on the internet?